# general solution of the equation $\frac{dy}{dx} =\exp(y/x)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

How can i get the general solution of the equation

a) $\frac{dy}{dx} = \exp(y/x)$

b) $\frac{dy}{dx} = \exp(x-y)$ and $y=2$ when $x = 0$

I tried b) first:

This is a first-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation, which is separable. 
General solution: 
$y(x) = \ln(C+e^x)$

Finding C , we have that:

$$2 = \ln(C + e^0)$$

$$ 2 = \ln(C + 1) $$ 
$$e^2 = C+1 $$ 
$$C = e^2 - 1 $$ 
Particular solution: 
$$y(x) = \ln(e^2 -1 + e^x)$$

Is that correct the solution for b)? , I stuck with a), some help please.

Comment: sorry i tried b), mistake

Comment: Try $y=x$ in b).

Comment: @Winther, that's $C=0$.  They got that covered.

Comment: b) has the correct solution then.

Comment: but in b i have the conditions $y=2$ and $x=0$ if i put $y=x$ i got $2= 0$ that´s imposible

Comment: But in A) i have to get a general solution and i stuck in that

Comment: I meant: YOUR solution is correct:)

Comment: a) a solution is $y = \alpha x$ where $\alpha\mathrm{e}^{-\alpha} = 1$. Well its the only one I have found so far.

Comment: For a) I only can find an implicit solution: $\int_a^{y/x}\frac{dz}{e^z-z} = \log(x) + C$. Don't think the integral can be inverted though.

Comment: I agree with Winther, can't go anywhere else except that ugly integral.

Comment: @Chinny84 Unfortunately, that equation only has a complex solution as $e^\alpha > \alpha$ for real $\alpha$.

Comment: @Winther Cheers, I didn't notice that in my argument :). I obtained a similar integral as yours with a different transformation but it does not look to friendly as well..

Comment: @Winther Holy crap. How did you arrive at that? Is it a complex analysis thing?

Comment: @BCLC Rewrite the ODE as $\frac{y' - y/x}{e^{y/x}-y/x} = 1$ and use $x(y/x)' = (y'-y/x)$ to get $\frac{1}{e^{y/x}-y/x} \frac{d(y/x)}{dx} = \frac{1}{x}$. Now integrate both sides to get the solution (on the left hand side take $z=y/x$).

Comment: @Winther I know how to use FTC man. I was just wondering how you came up with that integral in the first place. Is that SOP?

Comment: @BCLC Above it should read: 'Rewrite the ODE as'. That is the method I used:)

Comment: @Winther Know any textbooks with problems like that? I don't think I've ever encountered that in Calculus I-III, ODE, PDE or SDE. :O

Comment: @BCLC Can't think of any right now, but this kind of problem falls under the category 'separable ODE's' (see e.g. [this](http://www.wlu.ca/documents/59205/Separable.pdf)). There are many questions on this here like [1)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315973/general-solution-of-the-differential-equation-fracdydx-fracxyaxy?rq=1) , [2)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/602276/find-the-general-solution-of-the-differential-equation-fracdydx-x2yx2-y?rq=1), [3)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739284/help-with-separable-differential-equation-fracdydx-2y2?rq=1)

Comment: @Winther That's separable?

Comment: @BCLC The ODE $y' = e^{y/x}$ is not directly separable, but it can (using the steps I did above) be turned into the separable equation: $\frac{dz}{dz}\frac{1}{e^z-z} = \frac{1}{x}$ with $z=(y/x)$. To see that it can be written in this form is found by playing around with the equation, I don't think there is a 'general method' to see that this can be done.

Comment: @Winther Oh cool. Thanks. Btw, isn't supposed to be log|x| ? :P

Comment: @BCLC Yes it should:)

Comment: In Boyce and DiPrima, they refer to this kind of equation as 'homogeneous'. http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Substitutions.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a)

Approach $1$:

Let $u=\dfrac{y}{x}$ ,

Then $y=xu$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=x\dfrac{du}{dx}+u$

$\therefore x\dfrac{du}{dx}+u=e^u$

$x\dfrac{du}{dx}=e^u-u$

$\dfrac{dx}{x}=\dfrac{du}{e^u-u}$

$\int\dfrac{dx}{x}=\int\dfrac{du}{e^u-u}$

$\ln x=\int^u\dfrac{dt}{e^t-t}+c$

$x=Ce^{\int^\frac{y}{x}\frac{dt}{e^t-t}}$

Approach $2$:

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=e^\frac{y}{x}$

$\dfrac{dx}{dy}=e^{-\frac{y}{x}}$

Let $u=\dfrac{x}{y}$ ,

Then $x=yu$

$\dfrac{dx}{dy}=y\dfrac{du}{dy}+u$

$\therefore y\dfrac{du}{dy}+u=e^{-\frac{1}{u}}$

$y\dfrac{du}{dy}=e^{-\frac{1}{u}}-u$

$\dfrac{dy}{y}=\dfrac{du}{e^{-\frac{1}{u}}-u}$

$\int\dfrac{dy}{y}=\int\dfrac{du}{e^{-\frac{1}{u}}-u}$

$\ln y=\int^u\dfrac{dt}{e^{-\frac{1}{t}}-t}+c$

$y=Ce^{\int^\frac{x}{y}\frac{dt}{e^{-\frac{1}{t}}-t}}$

b)

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=e^{x-y}$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=e^xe^{-y}$

$e^y~dy=e^x~dx$

$\int_2^ye^y~dy=\int_0^xe^x~dx$

$[e^y]_2^y=[e^x]_0^x$

$e^y-e^2=e^x-1$

$e^y=e^x+e^2-1$

$y=\ln(e^x+e^2-1)$

Answer (score 1):

Set $y=xu$, then $y'=xu'+u$ and the equation a) transforms into
$$xu'+u=e^u \qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad  xu'=e^u-u.$$
This is obviously separable, hence the solution is implicitly given by
quadratures
$$\int^{y/x}\frac{du}{e^u-u}=\int\frac{dx}{x}=\ln x+\operatorname{const}.$$
However the integral on the left does not seem to be expressible in terms of elementary or classical special functions.